# Check if this file is opened in another program (7zip & notepad issue)

Tags: notepad++

While I open a text file with Notepad plus (which is placed in a `.zip` file and it was opened by `7zip`),
and I edit it and trying to save, it shows me warning error:

> Check if this file is opened in another program

How to solve? the file is not opened in another program.

p.s. no patches worked too. only one patch worked for a first time, but then the same occured..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Extract it** from the *.zip file before you edit it!

I don't know which file archiver you use, but most probably it locks the file as read-only.

Answer (score -1):

Disclaimer: It is a way around to complete the job but not an actual solution.

Prerequisite : You must have admin privileges on your system.

Copy that particular file to a different location for example say Desktop. Open that file on other location (Desktop) and edit & save it. Now you can copy and replace this file to original location.

Comment: Admin should not be needed. Please explain why you think it is.

Comment: If you are not admin then you might not be able to copy and replace the original file to desired location due to restricted access.

Comment: There is nothing in the original question to suggest that the file is not owned by the asker. The only reason to need admin access is if the ownership is different. Hence saying that an admin account is a prerequisite is just plain wrong.

Comment: It is a generic answer for a reference to all readers as well so saying that mentioning of prerequisite is plain wrong is wrong in itself, it is being completely ignorant of fact that answers also serves reference to all those readers who are facing the said issue.

Comment: OP is asking about the file INSIDE the archive, and not some system folder, so admin rights are irrelevant.

Answer (score -3):

The solution:

1) Enter in 7zip menu  TOOLS>Options>Editor and select other text editor (for example, simple one - [**Scite text editor**](http://www.ebswift.com/Common/ASPCommon/Download/file_download.aspx?File=/OpenSource/SciTEInstaller/scite-3.3.6.msi)) and click OK.

2) The in 7zip files list, click on any file, and click **F4** on keyboard